# unable to make api call from vue.js project hosted on firebase to node.js backend stored in third party server

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js

I am using node.js as backend and vue.js as frontend
Vue.js is project is hosted on firebase whereas node.js backend is hosted third party server
`http://113.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXX/`
I want my api calls to get proxy to this backend url but it seems like not working

package.json file for vue.js project

```
{
  "homepage": "https://xxxxx-xxx.web.app/",
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
}
```

vue.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/dist',
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api/':{
        target: 'http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:XXX/',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
      '^/u/api/':{
        target: 'http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:XXX/',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

API calls are getting proxied correctly in local environment when I run project locally using `npm run serve` but when I create its build using `npm run build` and host it on firebase no api calls are getting proxied

What I think issue is:
I suspect that proxy set using devServer only works for local environment (localhost) and not when project is in production mode.

Any help is appreciated... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was right
`devServer` property just works for development environments,

I created axios instance with `baseUrl = http://HOST_IP:PORT/` where you should replace host_ip and port with actual values

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:yyyy/',
});
```